# Return property of DbContext via generic method<T> by casting explicit type of the property to DbSet<T> (Entity framework core)

Tags: asp.net, generics, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am trying to port a database context to DotNet 7 and I am running into a problem.
I am trying to make a generic method to return the diffent context properties to use in a (also) generic repository class.

This is the code:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<UserProfile>, IDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    }

    public Context(DbContextOptions<AvgContext> options) :base(options) 
    { 

    }

    public DbSet<CustomTypeA> ObjectsA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomTypeB> ObjectsB { get; set; }

    public DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class
    {

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(CustomTypeA)) 
        {
            return ObjectsA as DbSet<T>;
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(CustomTypeB))
        {
            return ObjectsB as DbSet<T>;
        }

        throw new Exception($"Type '{typeof(T)}' does not exist in database context");
    }
}
```

However the cast `ObjectsA as DbSet<T>;` always returns 0. It seems ObjectsA is not a decendent of  DbSet. How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement the [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-7.0) method?

Comment: No, I am trying to implement a get method that take a generic type and the return the correct property of the DatabaseContext

Comment: Actually you need just `Set<T>()` method. Properties do the same under hood.

Comment: @Marth: that's what the method does. Have you consulted the linked documentation?

Comment: Ohw thanks! I does now great. I am trying for port this from an old version of dotnet. Guess the custom generic method is not needed anymore!

Comment: you can use the following code.  protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public CommandRepository(DbContext dbcontext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbcontext;
            _dbSet = dbcontext.Set<T>();
        }